# Parse PHP SDK ParseClient::setServerURL

Tags: php, parse-platform, sdk

My Parse php application runs perfectly without parse server configuration, when I configure the 
ParseClient::setServerURL('httpxXXXXXXXXXXX/parse'); my app doesn't runs.

Why?

Comment: The question is too vague. Did you include `AppId` and `MasterKey` correctly? Is Parse PHP SDK included in your project properly? What have you exactly done for integrating Parse PHP SDK so far?